# Expectation Value of a Non-Stationary State Wave Function and Problematic Calculated Uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Beginning with a system that has been prepared in a non-stationary state (not an eigenfunction of H),

[image: non stationary wave function]

we can calculate the expectation value of H this way :

[image]

We can also calculate the expectation value using probability amplitudes

[image]

with the probability amplitudes defined as

[image]

(I have skipped the detail of the integration)

So, the energy expectation value is

[image]

Which again reduces to

[image]

All of this makes sense; however, I have an issue with the calculated uncertainty using this wave function.

Calculating the square of the expectation value using the probability amplitudes and the uncertainty

[image]

Which makes no sense.

If we calculate the square of the expectation value the other way,

[image]

We have a fourth derivative that takes the square of the expectation value to zero and again produces a negative uncertainty squared.

Is the problem that the given wave function is impermissible? If the wave function was an oscillatory function (say a linear combination of energy eigenstates) that would seem to resolve the problem. On the other hand I have seen this non-oscillatory wave function used in several text books, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: See the well known paper by Guy Bonneau et al, *Self-adjoint operators and the teaching of quantum mechanics*, https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0103153.pdf